# Find if an object got recorder twice in less than 1 minute in sql

Tags: mysql, timestamp

So my table(image) is :

```
ID          keeper cameraID  WHN                
"SO 02 ASP"  1     1    "2007-02-25 06:10:13"   
"SO 02 ASP"  1     17   "2007-02-25 06:20:01"   
"SO 02 ASP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 06:23:40"   
"SO 02 ASP"  1     9    "2007-02-25 06:26:04"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     17   "2007-02-25 06:57:31"  
"SO 02 CSP"  1     17   "2007-02-25 07:00:40"  
"SO 02 CSP"  1     12   "2007-02-25 07:04:31"   
"SO 02 GSP"  6     5    "2007-02-25 07:10:00"   
"SO 02 GSP"  6     16   "2007-02-25 07:13:00"   
"SO 02 TSP"  6     2    "2007-02-25 07:20:01"  
"SO 02 TSP"  6     19   "2007-02-25 07:23:00"   
"SO 02 TSP"  6     19   "2007-02-25 07:26:31"   
"SO 02 TSP"  6     19   "2007-02-25 07:29:00"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     8    "2007-02-25 07:35:41"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 07:39:04"  
"SO 02 CSP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 07:42:30"  
"SO 02 CSP"  1     10   "2007-02-25 07:45:11"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     8    "2007-02-25 07:48:10"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     19   "2007-02-25 07:51:10"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 07:55:11"   
"SO 02 CSP"  1     11   "2007-02-25 07:58:01"   
"SO 02 SSP"  2     18   "2007-02-25 16:28:40"   
"SO 02 SSP"  2     9    "2007-02-25 16:31:01"   
"SO 02 RSP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 16:38:31"   
"SO 02 RSP"  1     9    "2007-02-25 16:39:10"   
"SO 02 HSP"  5     9    "2007-02-25 16:45:04"   
"SO 02 HSP"  5     9    "2007-02-25 16:48:11"   
"SO 02 HSP"  5     9    "2007-02-25 16:51:30"  
"SO 02 ISP"  6     9    "2007-02-25 16:58:01"   
"SO 02 ISP"  6     12   "2007-02-25 17:01:13"   
"SO 02 JSP"  2     3    "2007-02-25 17:07:00"   
"SO 02 JSP"  2     18   "2007-02-25 17:10:43"   
"SO 02 JSP"  2     19   "2007-02-25 17:14:11"   
"SO 02 JSP"  2     3    "2007-02-25 17:17:03"   
"SO 02 MUP"        10   "2007-02-25 18:23:11"   
"SO 02 NUP"        11   "2007-02-25 18:26:13"  
"SO 02 OUP"        12   "2007-02-25 18:29:01"   
"SO 02 PUP"        3    "2007-02-25 18:33:10"   
"SO 02 PUP"        15   "2007-02-25 18:36:31"   
"SO 02 PUP"        3    "2007-02-25 18:39:10"   
"SO 02 TSP"  6     10   "2007-02-26 05:13:30"   
"SO 02 DSP"  4     18   "2007-02-25 16:29:11"   
"SO 02 DSP"  4     19   "2007-02-25 16:31:01"   
"SO 02 DSP"  4     19   "2007-02-25 17:42:41"   
"SO 02 DSP"  4     9    "2007-02-25 18:54:30"   
"SO 02 ESP"  1     3    "2007-02-25 17:16:11"  
"SO 02 ESP"  1     10   "2007-02-25 18:08:40"  
"SO 02 FSP"  3     11   "2007-02-25 18:08:00"   
"SO 02 GSP"  6     12   "2007-02-25 18:08:13"
```

And i want to find if any ID(vehicle) has been caugh by any camera twice(it doesnt have to be the same cameraID) in less than a minute(WHN row)

example. One answer should be 'SO 02 RSP' which got recorded twice in less than a minute

```
"SO 02 RSP"  1     18   "2007-02-25 16:38:31"   "SO 02 RSP"
"SO 02 RSP"  1     9    "2007-02-25 16:39:10"   "SO 02 RSP"
```

i have done this :

```
select *
from image I1
where I1.reg in (SELECT I2.reg
              from image I2
              where I1.reg = I2.reg AND I1.whn - I2.whn < interval '1 minute')
```

but it doesnt work as i thought it would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not very far

```
select *
from image I1
where I1.id in (SELECT I2.id
              from image I2
              where I1.id = I2.id and I1.whn != i2.whn
                  and I1.whn between I2.whn - interval 1 minute
                                 and I2.whn + interval 1 minute) 
order by id, whn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question
But can you explain why my code ddnt work cause we litterally wrote the same thing
@nfgl Oh.btw it was my bad for the collumn named ID it was supposed to be called reg thats why in my code i had .reg

Comment: There were 3 errors, `interval '1 minute'`is not correct syntax,you can't compare timestamps and interval, and you had to add I1.whn != i2.whn or every record matches itself

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
( camera_id INT NOT NULL
, WHN DATETIME NOT NULL
, vehicle_id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY(camera_id,whn)
);

INSERT INTO my_table (vehicle_id,camera_id,whn) VALUES
("SO 02 ASP", 1   , "2007-02-25 06:10:13"),
("SO 02 ASP", 17  , "2007-02-25 06:20:01"),
("SO 02 ASP", 18  , "2007-02-25 06:23:40"),
("SO 02 ASP", 9   , "2007-02-25 06:26:04"),
("SO 02 CSP", 17  , "2007-02-25 06:57:31"),
("SO 02 CSP", 17  , "2007-02-25 07:00:40"),
("SO 02 CSP", 12  , "2007-02-25 07:04:31"),
("SO 02 GSP", 5   , "2007-02-25 07:10:00"),
("SO 02 GSP", 16  , "2007-02-25 07:13:00"),
("SO 02 TSP", 2   , "2007-02-25 07:20:01"),
("SO 02 TSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 07:23:00"),
("SO 02 TSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 07:26:31"),
("SO 02 TSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 07:29:00"),
("SO 02 CSP", 8   , "2007-02-25 07:35:41"),
("SO 02 CSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 07:39:04"),
("SO 02 CSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 07:42:30"),
("SO 02 CSP", 10  , "2007-02-25 07:45:11"),
("SO 02 CSP", 8   , "2007-02-25 07:48:10"),
("SO 02 CSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 07:51:10"),
("SO 02 CSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 07:55:11"),
("SO 02 CSP", 11  , "2007-02-25 07:58:01"),
("SO 02 SSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 16:28:40"),
("SO 02 SSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:31:01"),
("SO 02 RSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 16:38:31"),
("SO 02 RSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:39:10"),
("SO 02 HSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:45:04"),
("SO 02 HSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:48:11"),
("SO 02 HSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:51:30"),
("SO 02 ISP", 9   , "2007-02-25 16:58:01"),
("SO 02 ISP", 12  , "2007-02-25 17:01:13"),
("SO 02 JSP", 3   , "2007-02-25 17:07:00"),
("SO 02 JSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 17:10:43"),
("SO 02 JSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 17:14:11"),
("SO 02 JSP", 3   , "2007-02-25 17:17:03"),
("SO 02 MUP", 10  , "2007-02-25 18:23:11"),
("SO 02 NUP", 11  , "2007-02-25 18:26:13"),
("SO 02 OUP", 12  , "2007-02-25 18:29:01"),
("SO 02 PUP", 3   , "2007-02-25 18:33:10"),
("SO 02 PUP", 15  , "2007-02-25 18:36:31"),
("SO 02 PUP", 3   , "2007-02-25 18:39:10"),
("SO 02 TSP", 10  , "2007-02-26 05:13:30"),
("SO 02 DSP", 18  , "2007-02-25 16:29:11"),
("SO 02 DSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 16:31:01"),
("SO 02 DSP", 19  , "2007-02-25 17:42:41"),
("SO 02 DSP", 9   , "2007-02-25 18:54:30"),
("SO 02 ESP", 3   , "2007-02-25 17:16:11"),
("SO 02 ESP", 10  , "2007-02-25 18:08:40"),
("SO 02 FSP", 11  , "2007-02-25 18:08:00"),
("SO 02 GSP", 12  , "2007-02-25 18:08:13"); 

SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.vehicle_id = x.vehicle_id 
   AND 
     ( y.whn > x.whn AND y.whn < x.whn + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    OR x.whn > y.whn AND x.whn < y.whn + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
     );

+-----------+---------------------+------------+
| camera_id | WHN                 | vehicle_id |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
|        18 | 2007-02-25 16:38:31 | SO 02 RSP  |
|         9 | 2007-02-25 16:39:10 | SO 02 RSP  |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+
```